# Python return sum of list where 5 counts as double and the number after 5 counts quadruple

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, control-flow

Given a list, return a sum of all the numbers in the list. However, if the number 5 appears in the list, you have to double it and the number that immediately comes after 5 needs to be quadrupled. So the following list [1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2] should return 26 and [5, 1, 6] should return 20.

This is what I have so far:

```
def list_sum(x):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum2 = 0
        for i in x:
            if i == 5:
                sum2 += 5*2
            if x[i - 1] == 5:
                sum2 += i * 4
            else:
                sum2 += i
       
    return sum2
```

I can successfully do the first part of the problem where I multiply any 5s in the list by 2 but having trouble with the second part where I have to ask the code to quadruple the number that comes after 5. I was thinking `x[i - 1] == 5` would basically be indexing the element that comes after 5 but after trying out a few print statements, it came to my attention that that line of code isn't really doing anything... So any tips?

Quick note: only using loops and if statements to solve this problem

Comment: `if x[i - 1] == 5:` that's wrong, you iterate over elements of your list, not indices

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: What if there are two `5`s in a row? What should `[1, 5, 5]` return? `51`?

Comment: Did you try using a separate variable to remember whether the previous value was 5? When you see a 5, set it so that you can check it on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Define a variable and change it when 5 occurs

```
def list_sum(x):
    IfFive = False
    if len(x) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        sum2 = 0
        for i in x:
            if i == 5:
                sum2 += 5*2
                IfFive = True
            elif IfFive:
                sum2 += i * 4
                IfFive = False
            else:
                sum2 += i
       
    return sum2
```

Result:

```
print(list_sum([5, 1, 6]))
>>> 20
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this (iterate over range of length of the input list instead:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 4, 1, 5, 2] 
def list_sum(thelist):
  sum2 = 0
  for x in range(len(thelist)):
    if thelist[x] == 5:
      sum2 += 5*2
    elif thelist[x-1] == 5:
      sum2 += thelist[x]*4
    else:
      sum2 += thelist[x]
   
  return sum2

print(list_sum(mylist))
```

Comment: I would expect `mylist = [1, 5] ` to result in `11`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @MarkMeyer I am also getting it. While posting it I tested with OP examples and they worked. Do you have any idea in this case?

Comment: @Wasif Hasan I edited your ```elif``` line to ```elif thelist[x-1] == 5 and not thelist[-1] == 5:``` and that fixed the issue. So before, if 5 was the last item in the list, the code would consider the ```thelist[x-1]``` to be the first item of the list and it would get quadrupled